# Google Play Console: my app have numer of active user lower than install. How can it be?

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-console-developer

Active user"s is "The number of users who have your app installed on at least one device that was active in the preceding 30 days".

And I already get many installed but active users very low (just 30% compared to install). I wonder how can someone install an app if they don't open their device? Because, if they open their device they will be count an active user. Isn't it right?

Can you explain to me, please?

Comment: this question doesnt belong to SO, in here we are asking questions about programming... but answering: how about those who installed, tried once and then uninstalled?

Answer (score 0):

Active User Formula

> Active Users= Total Install - Total Uninstall

Comment: thank you for answer my question. I have checked it out and it pretty right

Comment: I know its an old post but for me its still wrong. It shows 214 new aquired users - 101 uninstalls and it shows only 13 active users.

Answer (score 0):

Active user means that the number of users currently installed your application on their device (atleast one). The count is not based on the app uses.
 You can track your real time users by implementing google analytics or firebase analytics:

- https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/
- https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317517#active-users

Comment: welcome, please mark as correct answer if it really helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to your respective app "dashboard"
2. Change the timeframe to lifetime
3. The "installs by user" card will show the total installs